Why can't we measure different properties of an electron in accordance with its frequency?
sorry if this is a stupid question but its my first one.. Why cant we just observe and electron in accordance to its frequency. Like during one frequency peak we could observe position, next could be accel, and the final could be spin.

I understand observation can impact the wave, couldn't you do an "inverse" to the observation? if observing something one way impacts the wave one way, couldnt you observe it a different way to reset the modification and still observe it again during these peaks?


You cannot observe the wave function. You can only observe the electron, which is a point particle as far as we know it. The wave function gives the probability of its location and other properties.

"frequency peak", huh, Are you sure ? Maybe you mean wave amplitude peak ?

The question is essentially: can we "undo" the effect of a first measurement on a state, in order to subsequently do a second measurement. If so, then the things you propose would be possible.
But there are two reasons why it is not possible.

After the first measurement you get an entangled state of the system under test and the measurement device. In principle this can be undone, all possible results are still present in a big superposition. But if the measurement device is monitored by yet another system (a storage device, or a human experimenter, it doesn't matter) then this is a new influence which should be undone as well. And if the storage device is read out by another system this adds yet another system in the entangled state. It quickly becomes impossible to undo everything, but even if you could, you'd get the situation that there would be no trace left of the result. So: you can only undo the measurement if you don't use the result.
Even if you have only the system under test and the measurement device, without doing anything else, the state after measurement is extremely sensitive to influences of the environment. This is because a measurement device usually is designed to give us clearly discernible states for the different outcomes. It is meant to make the result visible in the macroscopic world. But to obtain this, its states must have larger differences in energy levels and spatial positions, which makes them very sensitive to tiny variations in things like electric potential, mechanical vibrations, or even passing neutrinos or gravitational waves. This quickly leads to intractable phase changes of the components of the state for the different outcomes of the measurement (remember, we are still in a superposition with all possibilities present). So then we don't know the correct state any more and cannot undo it.

The second problem is only of practical nature (in theory all environment influences might be shielded or suppressed) but the first problem is fundamental. If you can't undo everything that was influenced by the measurement result, your electron will be entangled with those other systems and cannot be back in the old state. It can only be described by a mixed state, which makes a big difference if you do a second measurement (or even a third, as you propose). So it is essential to understand entanglement to understand the problems.
